# I got Error when I tried to use animation Skeleton widget in if-else method '_debugLifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true."

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to show skeleton widget while the data still loading so I used if-else in FutureBuilder widget.

Here the skeleton code

```
class Skeleton extends StatefulWidget {
  final double height;
  final double width;

  Skeleton({Key key, this.height = 20, this.width = 200 }) : super(key: key);

  createState() => SkeletonState();
}

class SkeletonState extends State<Skeleton> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  Animation gradientPosition;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500), vsync: this);

    gradientPosition = Tween<double>(
      begin: -3,
      end: 10,
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _controller,
        curve: Curves.linear
      ),
    )..addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });

    _controller.repeat();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width:  widget.width,
        height: widget.height, 
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment(gradientPosition.value, 0),
            end: Alignment(-1, 0),
            colors: [Colors.black12, Colors.black26, Colors.black12]
          )
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here I tried to use the skeleton widget

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: CategoryService.list(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                print(snapshot.error);
                return snapshot.hasData
                    ? SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        child: CategoryList(
                          categories: snapshot.data,
                        ),
                      )
                    : snapshot.hasError
                        ? Text(
                            snapshot.error.toString(),
                          )
                        : Skeleton(
                            height: 200,
                            width: 200,
                          );
              },
            ),
```

Then I got this Error

> Exception caught by animation library
>
> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
> 4182 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is
> not true.
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> Another exception was thrown:
> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
> 4182 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is
> not true.

I got this Error but the App still running without problem but this Error shows in Debug console and always repeat the Error all time while the screen is running.

I did reload and I stop it and re run it but that was useless, I think the problem in the dispose of Skeleton widget.

Comment: did you means like this ` if (snapshot.hasData) return SingleChildScrollView( scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, child: CategoryList( categories: snapshot.data, ), ); snapshot.hasError ? Text(snapshot.error.toString()) : Skeleton( height: 200, width: 200, );`
will the Error is fixed but I got another Error but it's shows for one time in debug console only and the app still running.
@Reign

Comment: the error is: `EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<Category>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<List<Category>>#4e9c2): A build function returned null. The offending widget is: FutureBuilder<List<Category>> Build functions must never return null. To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return "Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return "Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)". The relevant error-causing widget was: FutureBuilder<List<Category>>....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can move `_controller.dispose();` before `super.dispose();` 
code snippet

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Skeleton extends StatefulWidget {
  final double height;
  final double width;

  Skeleton({Key key, this.height = 20, this.width = 200}) : super(key: key);

  createState() => SkeletonState();
}

class SkeletonState extends State<Skeleton>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  Animation gradientPosition;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500), vsync: this);

    gradientPosition = Tween<double>(
      begin: -3,
      end: 10,
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.linear),
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });

    _controller.repeat();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: widget.width,
      height: widget.height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment(gradientPosition.value, 0),
              end: Alignment(-1, 0),
              colors: [Colors.black12, Colors.black26, Colors.black12])),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class CategoryService {
  static Future<String> list() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {});
    return Future.value("123");
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: CategoryService.list(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          print(snapshot.error);
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  child: Text(
                    snapshot.data,
                  ),
                )
              : snapshot.hasError
                  ? Text(
                      snapshot.error.toString(),
                    )
                  : Skeleton(
                      height: 200,
                      width: 200,
                    );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```